# Is it possible to push local notifications with live data using react native fcm?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-fcm, react-native-push-notification

Let's say I am building an app that sends push notifications with react-native-fcm using data retrieved from a weather API.

currently, I have this script, but the notifications sent only contains weather information that I retrieved before scheduling, not the most current weather:

```
FCM.scheduleLocalNotification({
  fire_date: moment().add(5, 'seconds').toDate().getTime(),
  id: '1q2we3',
  body: `${ ...weatherInfo... }`,
  repeat_interval: 'hour',
  show_in_foreground: true
});
```

even if I were to place 'body' with Date.now(), the notifications sent later will have the date string at the time of scheduling the notification, not the time of the notification being pushed.

**TLDR**:

Basically I was wondering if it was possible to schedule **local** push notifications that fetches data before sending the message. If not, what are my alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the scheduled notification fire `FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {});`. If so fetch the data  and dispatch a local notif from there

Comment: I tried dispatching local notification there but it ended up causing a circular loop

Comment: Yes, Imight be possible. You need some logic to identify what action should be taken based on the receiven notification

Comment: Thank you, after exploring this a bit more, I found that it is indeed possible to do this